# SOT-23 footprint (difference between KiCAD footprint and NXP)

Tags: pcb, kicad, sot23

I'm using some transistors in SOT-23 packages, designing a board in KiCAD 7.

- NXP's recommended footprint has pads 0.6 x 0.7 mm. [Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/package-information/SOT23.pdf)
- Vishay's "recommended minimum" has pads 0.559 x 0.725 mm [Datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/67030/si2318cds.pdf)
- KiCAD's pads are *much* bigger 0.6 x 1.475 mm (`Package TO SOT SMD:SOT-23`)
- KiCAD's "handsolder" variant even bigger: 0.8 x 1.9 mm (`Package TO SOT SMD:SOT-23_Handsoldering`)

**What advantages are there to such long pads?  Can I simply shorten them to, say, 0.8 mm long?**

I can only see thermal advantage; as a disadvantage it's making my tracking a little difficult, as I'd like to send a signal up from pin 2 between 1 and 3.

[image]
From KiCAD 7.0.6 footprint

[image]
From [NXP SOT-23 packaging information](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/package-information/SOT23.pdf)

Comment: Easier to solder (by hand) and sure; you can reproduce entirely what a data sheet recommends.

Comment: Is that one of the "handsolder" variants?  Many of the footprints have a larger, easier-to-solder version.

Comment: @rdtsc No, it was the "plain" variant.  Updated question with dimension of handsolder variant, clarified footprint names.

Comment: I bet KiCAD is generalizing for *any* SOT-23 device, while this part is "small" for a SOT-23.  I'd say to take that footprint, copy it into your own private library, and trim it down closer to the recommended size.  I've made it a habit to have parts onhand, then print a 1:1 paper output of the board with all footprints on it, then physically match each component to the footprint, all before sending for board fab.  Invariably, a few are found which need adjustment - sometimes minor, sometimes major.

Comment: @rdtsc Thanks for good advice.  I'm in the habit of library-per-project in any case, so that no library updates change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm answering myself by collecting the very helpful comments and answers from others.*

> - "sure; you can reproduce entirely what a data sheet recommends." (@AndyAka)
> - "I bet KiCAD is generalizing for any SOT-23 device, while this part is "small" for a SOT-23. I'd say to take that footprint, copy it into your own private library, and trim it down closer to the recommended size." (@rdtsc)
> - "It all depends on how the PCB will be fabricated and assembled.
>   On my last PCB I used a default footprint from the alitum library for SOT23. The pads are 0.6mm by 1.15mm." (@petergreen)

Thanks, I made a footprint which matches the datasheet.
[image]

In the end, I made the pads a little bigger to help with thermal connection.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the PCB will be fabricated and assembled.

On my last PCB I used a default footprint from the alitum library for SOT23. The pads are 0.6mm by 1.15mm. So smaller than the Kicad default but larger than what your Manufacturer recommends.

The PCB was a pretty basic design. I had a lot of through-hole connectors and decided to go for a hand-soldered "mostly through-hole" approach rather than bothering with stencils and solder paste. However I needed some parts that were not available in through-hole including some SOT23 mosfets. I got it fabricated by my Universities in-house PCB facility. The in-house PCB facility is fast and convenient, but the immersion tin and dry film soldermask processes they use seem to leave boards with less than stellar solderability

After I constructed and tested the board I discovered that out of 17 SOT23 mosfets two had not soldered properly. In one case I was able to rectify this with application of more heat and solder. In the other case though I had to completely remove the transistor so I could clean/tin the pads before making another attempt at soldering.

If I had pads that extended further beyond the transistor I suspect I could have fixed it without removing said transistor.

So sure, if you are doing a dense SMT design that will be fabricated by a good quality PCB manufacturer and assembled by a proffesional assembly house, then smaller pads are probablly ok. If that is not the case, you may make other judgements.

If you are going to hand solder this, but want more space under the transistor then I would be tempted to keep the pad size as it is, but increase the gap between them a bit. Extra pad under the part doesn't really help with hand soldering.